# Mackey's Program on Algebraic Ergodic Theory

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, oa.operator-algebras, ergodic-theory

I knew about Mackey's Program from Arnold's book *Random Dynamical Systems* and it referred to K. Schmidt's book *Algebraic Ideas in Ergodic Theory*, which was published in 1990. However, that is the latest book I could find on this topic.

I wonder if there is any progress in recent 25 years. It would be of great help if someone could let me know if there are any recent books or papers about Mackey's program or algebraic ergodic theory.